# Icons in WPF when to use image and when to use Xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am Working on a WPF based project where the design team have created the design in blend with some images like Edit, delete, checkbox etc. where i am prefring to use xaml insteed of images

Although i am sure that if the images are prety complex they should be used as images. but the simple im icon images can be used as xaml path designs. So i am looking for the recomandations. When to use Images in WPF design and When to use xaml for design.

Answer (score 2):

If your application is going to be used in different screen resolutions then using Vector Graphics is recommended as they will scale nicely and all your images will look sharp regardless of the resolution of the screen. (There is a downside as well because your application needs to do the extra rendering of the xaml images to display them)

If you are using the images just to display the toolbar images (which are pretty much small and fixed size then you can get away by using png files as they will take less resources and easy to manage)